# Batch rename files how to loop in order of filename?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, file-rename

I have a bunch of jpg files named IMG_0001, IMG_0002, etc. The problem was that there I had to delete a couple of them, so I need to rename the files to fill in the gaps. In essence,

IMG_0001, IMG_0002, IMG_0004, IMG_0006

are renamed

IMG_0001, IMG_0002, IMG_0003, IMG_0004.

Thus filling in the gaps caused by the files I deleted. However, the bat file I wrote to do this sometimes jumbles the files out of order, so what was originally IMG_0001 would become IMG_0002, and IMG_0003 would become IMG_0001. How can I ensure that my bat file loops through the files in order of name?

This is my bat file:

```
@echo off
set i=1
set y=0000
for %%f in (*.jpg) do call :renameit "%%f"
goto done

:renameit
set x=%y%%i%
ren %1 IMG_%x:~-4%.jpg
set /A i+=1

:done
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think FOR supports ordering on its own, but DIR does with the `/on` ("order by name") switch. So, try replacing your FOR loop with this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /on *.jpg') do call :renameit "%%f"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /a-d /on /b "IMG_*.jpg"^|findstr /n "^"') do (
    set /a "n=%%a+10000"
    ren "%%b" "IMG_!n:~-4!.jpg"
)
```

This just uses findstr to numerate the list of retrieved files (each lines is in the format number:filename) and uses this numeration to do the rename of files.